# How to get own failure info in case of failed SageMaker Training Job?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-sagemaker

**My main purpose:** Easy way to collect information about different failure scenarios in SageMaker TrainingJob.

**What do I use currently?**

Sagemaker SKLearn Estimator(TrainingJobs are inside)

**Where will my model train?**

Different datasets. So, I need control and collect all information about all training processes and their final statuses on different datasets.

**Which failure scenarios do I have?**

There are plenty of them. I have create my own python Errors for them.
For example: 1. There are labels only for one class. 2. Too small dataset(by my own criterions) 3. Missing data for crucial columns 4. e.t.c.

**Where am I stuck?**

After failed training I can't get own errors from training job response. All of them are `ExecuteUserScriptError` I can't pass my own info in `FailureReason` or `ErrorMessage`(always it's empty). I see which error was raised in CloudWatchLogs and TrainingJob Failure Traceback(from SagemakerNotebook). So, bad solution is parse CloudWatchLogs or `/opt/ml/output/failure` in case of failure with Lambda function.

**Question: How to provide my own `ErrorMessage` or `FailureReason` in TrainingJob description?**

Comment: What about using your own estimator's `metric_definitions` to get info from training logs after a failure?